# Adobe AIR, how to open a scene in a new window

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I'm developing a networked AIR application in Flash Professional.  I need to open two instances of the application and after searching I found that launching the app multiple times just causes an invoke event to be sent to the currently running app.

Up until now I've been using NetConnection & NetGroup (Supported by Flash Player 10.1+), now that I'm using ServerSocket & Socket, it requires the AIR 2+ runtime.

[I found a solution to open a window on invoke.](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=254267)

my solution would be to launch a new window on invoke

```
function openWindow():void
{
newWin = new NativeWindow(init); //Initialize the Native Window
newWin.activate();
newWin.height = 200;
newWin.width = 300;
newWin.title = "My First New Win!";
}
```

and have it

```
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1");
```

Is there a way to execute that on the new window? Or is there a way to open two instances of an AIR app?

*Edit*
You can open two instances of the same air app by changing it's ID.  However, this is a very involved process every time I want to debug!

Comment: If you're trying to test as though you have two clients communicating maybe you should consider running a virtual box instance with ubuntu in it, I'm pretty sure they have AIR support up to 2.6, then you would just share a folder from your host OS to the virtual box linux and have your build point to there (or just have it share the bin-debug from your project).  It'd still be somewhat convoluted but maybe not as bad as the things you've been trying so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out AIR on Android doesn't support ServerSockets.  This means I must use non-AIR flash methods to achieve communication.

I can then achieve network testing through multiple Flash Player instances.

I don't believe ADL has the ability to run more than instance at a time.